# How to select a value from list in table under class of type input

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
  <ul class="rcbList" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;"><li class="rcbItem  rcbTemplate">
  <table style="width: 415px">
  <tbody><tr>
  <td style="width: 175px;"> </td>
  <td style="width: 125px;"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>
  </li><li class="rcbItem  rcbTemplate">
  <table style="width: 415px">
  <tbody><tr>
  <td style="width: 175px;">Production Strategy</td>
  <td style="width: 125px;">48</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>
```

I have tried below:

```
    WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_MainContent_RadComboBoxStrategyList_Input']"));
    actions.moveToElement(menu);
    actions.click(menu);
    actions.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
    actions.doubleClick();
```

And

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_MainContent_RadComboBoxStrategyList_DropDown']/div[2]/ul/li[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")).click();
```

Comment: Can you sumup the exact Manual steps you are trying to Automate?

Comment: I'm trying to select "Production Strategy" from the dropdown list

Comment: I tried below and saw error "element not visible".                                                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_MainContent_RadComboBoxStrategyList_DropDown']/div[2]/ul/li[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")).click();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select `Production Strategy` from the `Dropdown` list you can use the following line of code :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='rcbList']/li[@class='rcbItem  rcbTemplate']//td[contains(.,'Production Strategy')]"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions. elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@class='rcbList']/li[@class='rcbItem  rcbTemplate']//td[contains(.,'Production Strategy')]"))).click();
```

Comment: I have tried this but seeing same error which was seen when xpath is used."org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible"

Comment: Updated my Answer. Let me know the Status.

Comment: Thank you , this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

First click the drop down, then click the value by text:

```
// click dropdown   
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MainContent_RadComboBoxStrategyList_DropDown")).click(); 

// wait and click by text
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Production Strategy)));
element.click();
```

Comment: Even this was not helpful as it timedout because of the invisibility of the element

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Confirm if need to click on some element, then the options will display out, If so click that element firstly, I'm not sure below code from your posted can archive that, if not get the correct element to click.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MainContent_RadComboBoxStrategyList_DropDown")).click();
```

**2)** Choose the option, if the options need more than 10 seconds to load before display, please add wait before choose.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(.,'Production Strategy')]")).click();
```